# Get JS code in a input element to string and append to variable without executing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea which could have js code, and when I try to read and put it in a variable it is executed. Is there a way to avoid executing it and keep the code?

I am doing:

```
'<script>'+$("#EJs").val()+'</script>'
```

more info:
I have two textareas, the first one with html code and the second with js:

```
$("#text1").on('change', function (){
parser = new DOMParser();
html2 = parser.parseFromString($("#text1").val(), "text/html");

js1 = $(html2).find('body').detach('script');
js2 = $('<script>'+$("#text2").val()+'</script>');

$(html2).find('body').append(js1);
$(html2).find('body').append(js2);
```

}

The second append executes the code, but the one I got from  tags on the first textarea are not executed. And I want to know why, and a possible a way around - I dont want the code to be executed.

Comment: `eval` the evil, but **probably** better than what you have... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: but eval would execute it, I dont want the code in $("#EJs") to run, I just want the code

Comment: I see. I thought you were creating a script element.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example through http://jsfiddle.net. I don't think I understand.

Comment: *"I have a textarea which could have js code, and when I try to read and put it in a variable it is executed."* Then you are doing something weird. `var txt = textarea.value;` does **not** execute the code.

Comment: I am trying to put an example on fiddle but I having problems there
jsfiddle.net/5CQEp

Comment: @VictorSoares You better know the rules first. There is no relation between question asked and code placed in your question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5CQEp/

Comment: You forgot to mention an important fact: this question is about `DOMParser`...

Comment: I did not know it was about it when I asked... but anyway, the answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem...

```
var code = $("#EJs").val();
```

If you put anything between script tags, it will run, just like by `eval()`. The `val()` returns the code as js string.

**edit**

Ohh, so you are using DOMParser to build a HTML page, and it runs the javascript code.

If you append a script element with js code inside to the DOM, it will evaluate the content of your script tag. You cannot prevent that... Try to use XML DOM instead of HTML DOM, maybe it will work without this side-effect.

```
html2 = parser.parseFromString($("#text1").val(), "text/xml");
```

or if the textarea contains just the js string, you can do

```
var script = html2.createElement("script");
script.appendChild(html2.createTextNode($("#text2").val()));
html2.appendChild(script);
```

So the important thing here, that the HTML you want to edit should be in an XML DOM not in a HTML DOM.

Comment: $("#EJs").val() contains a text, that happens to be a js code and I want the string

Comment: @VictorSoares what code is it running? Unless you do something with `code`, this doesn't execute any user input.

Comment: I am testing with alerts.

Comment: Make some jsfiddle pls, I don't understand your problem, `val()` should not evaluate any input from the textarea... Maybe your code is wrong in some way we cannot find out without checking it...

Comment: I got the issue: $(html).find('body').append(jsEmbutido);
 $(html).find('body').append(js);

Comment: it is weird, the code on the first one dont execute but the second executes.

Comment: I am also having problems there

Comment: Ohh, so you are using DOMParser to build a HTML page, and it runs the javascript code.